# How does rewrite URL and 301 redirection work together

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've got:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Which points `page/([^/\.]+)/?` to `index.php?page=$1`.

When I go to `page/([^/\.]+)/`, I don't want to see index.php (which is achieved from the above)

For the reverse, when I go to index.php, I **want to** see a visible 301 redirection to `page/([^/\.]+)/`.

How do I do this without causing an infinite loop... or do I only rely on canonical tags?

**Update:**

I got it happening in one direction (new to old), but not the other (Old to new)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-yum/?$ yum/?x=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)-yum/?$ yum/?x=$2&y=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a check against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable so that you are rewriting *only* when the actual request is for the index.php file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?page=([^&]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /page/%1/?%2 [L,R=301]
```

So if a browser requests `http://yourdomain.com/index.php?page=qwe&someother=var`

It should get redirected to: `http://yourdomain.com/page/qwe/?someother=var`

Comment: Couldn't get this to work, does it work for both directions when page/qwe/ is actually mapped to index.php

Comment: @bcm this only does it for one direction, when someone requests `index.php`, you still need the stuff that you had working going in the other direction

Answer (score 0):

**Full solution here:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Variable=([A-Za-z]+)$
RewriteRule OldURL/$ /NewURL/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^NewUrl/([^/\.]+)$ MappedNewLocationFolder/?Variable=$1 [L]
```

**1st Line:** Check (the name and number of) parameters are as expected

**2nd Line:** Check base path of parameter(s), which is OldURL is correct and 301 to NewUrl

**3rd Line:** Map NewUrl to actual location where file sits (not shown in browser)

(The question mark right at the end of 2nd line strips out the variables from appending to the NewUrl)